# React: Can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component. When using `useLocation()`

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-hooks

So here is my problem. I have:

```
const nav = useHistory();
const location = useLocation();
```

There is DOM that uses `location` to determine its class.

```
<IonItem className={location.pathname === appPage.url ? 'selected' : ''} routerLink={appPage.url} routerDirection="none" lines="none" detail={false}>
```

Then when I call:

```
nav.push('/');
```

It produces error:

> index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted
> component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your
> application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks
> in a useEffect cleanup function.

If I traced it, that `useLocation()` is changed when I call `nav.push('/')`. This triggers DOM update on `<IonItem>` to check the `className`.

How can I prevent this?

---

### CODE

```
const Menu: React.FC = () => {
    
    const location = useLocation();
    const nav = useHistory();

    const logout = () => {
        nav.push('/');
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3 className={location.pathname === '/account' ? 'selected' : ''}>Title</h3>
            <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Menu;
```

The `nav.push('/')` creates problem, because it changes the `location` which triggers DOM update.

Comment: Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we may see what the code is doing?

Comment: Are you using useEffect inside of your code?

Comment: I included my code, please kindly check.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping track of the reference of the mounted component.

```
const Menu: React.FC = () => {
    
    const location = useLocation();
    const nav = useHistory();

    // Use a ref to maintain the mounted state across component re-renders 
    const mountedRef = useRef(false);

    // just for tracking mounted state
    useEffect(() => {
        mountedRef.current = true;
        return () => {
            mountedRef.current = false;  
        }
    }, [])

    const logout = () => {
        if(mountedRef.current) {
            nav.push('/');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3 className={location.pathname === '/account' ? 'selected' : ''}>Title</h3>
            <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
    )

}

export default Menu;
```

Source: https://www.benmvp.com/blog/handling-async-react-component-effects-after-unmount/